# Cart Checkout >> Send an Email with Cart Items included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an "Add To Cart" function working fine based on Sessions so no user is currently logged in.

Here's the Model

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tutors

  def add_tutor(tutor_id)
    tutor = Tutor.find(tutor_id)
    if tutor
      self.tutors << tutor
    end
    save
  end
end
```

Here's the Controller

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @cart = current_cart
  end

  def add_to_cart
    current_cart.add_tutor(params[:tutor_id])
    redirect_to tutors_path
  end

end
```

What i would like to do is when the user checkouts, they will be redirected to a page with a simple form requesting for their name/email/phone-number, and when that email is sent to me, it includes the items in their cart.

I am currently using `gem 'mail_form'` and this is what i have set-up so far.

Model `checkout.rb`

```
class Checkout < MailForm::Base
  attribute :name,      :validate => true
  attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
  attribute :hp,        :validate => true


  def headers
    {
     :subject => "Tutor Checkout",
     :to => "xxx@xxx.com"
    }
  end

end
```

Controller `checkouts_controller.rb`

```
class CheckoutsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @checkout = Checkout.new
  end

  def create
    @checkout = Checkout.new(params[:checkout])
    @checkout.request = request
    if @checkout.deliver
      flash[:notice] = 'Thank you! We will be in touch with you shortly!'
    else
      flash[:error] = 'There was an error in sending your message!'
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

and under `views/checkouts/new.html.erb` its just a form requesting for their information.

What i really have no idea on where to start is creating the association between `Carts` and `Checkouts` and how do i even include the items in the cart to be sent along with the email?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: Association should be checkout has_many carts. Cart has_many tutors. Right? Then you can call the checkouts cart, and all the tutors associated with that cart.